# Is there any way to use IHostingEnvironment in .net core class library?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

In my application I am saving some image files into the application folder itself. Currently using `IHostingEnvironment` interface for getting the Path. 
like

```
private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ProductController"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="unitService">The product service.</param>
        public ProductController(IProductService productService, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            this._productService = productService;
            this._hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }
```

for getting path using this code `_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath`

But in future we may change the image location to cloud or some other places, so I have written an extension method for getting the actual path

```
public static class AssetPathHandlerExtensions
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;//error

        public static string AppendAssetPath(this string fileName, string subDirectryPath)
        {
           //here i need to get the ContentRootPath and append it with filename
        }
    }
```

This extension method is there in a class library and I am calling this extension method from `automapper` Mapping .

The issue I am facing is I cannot use  `IHostingEnvironment`  in class library because of it does not contain `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll` assembly.

Is there any way to use `IHostingEnvironment`  in the class library ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no problem to use **IHostingEnvironment** in your class library. Simply install its NuGet package using this command in your class library:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
```

And resolve **IHostingEnviroment** from your DI Container like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public SomeClass(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Use IHostingEnvironment with _hostingEnvironment here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input , but how can i refer Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting , i couldnt find it in the add reference window

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV Your welcome, Simply install it via NuGet: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore. This is why Stack Overflow wants you to put code samples in the answers and not just a link.

Comment: You right, answer updated with the code sample. @Kurt